# Homomorphism between groups and group order

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $φ: G \to \mathbb{Z_{15}}$ be a group Homomorphism and $ord(G) = n$.

Are the following true or false?

1. 15|n
2. n|15

All I know is that for $a\in G, ord(φ(a))|ord(a)$, but I can't seem to be getting anywhere from here. Any tips?

Comment: Do you mean ord(G)=n?

Comment: What is $n$ here?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I meant ord(G) = n

Comment: None of them is right. Try $G=\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $G=\mathbb{Z}_{30}$.

Comment: @Yanko In both instances you mention either $\;n\mid15\;$ or $\;15\mid n\;$ ...

Comment: I think there should be more assumptions on $\varphi$ to deduce any kind of equation. Right now, take any group and consider the trivial morphism $\varphi : G\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ that sends $g\mapsto 0$ for all $g\in G$.

Comment: @DonAntonio I know, but the first is a counter-example for 1 and the second for 2.

Comment: @Yanko Oh, I see. Thanks.

Comment: @Yanko  I was trying to find a counter-example and I somehow missed Z3, thanks! I thought I was missing something from theory.

Answer (score 0):

With no additional assumption, there is no way to deduce any kind of equation (you can check my comment above). However, if $\varphi$ is surjective, you can take $g\in G$ with $\varphi(g)=1$ and then deduce that order of $g$ is divisible by $15$ which implies that the order of $G$ is divisible by $15$.